# Как добавить несколько payment_type для одного заказа используя check_box?

Tags: ruby

У меня есть база данных `projects` и `payment_types`.

В модели Project установлена связь: `has_and_belongs_to_many :payment_types`
В модели PaymentType установлена связь: `has_and_belongs_to_many :projects`

При создании нового проекта пользователь выбирает через чек боксы какие виды платежа можно использовать. 
Не совсем понятно как сохранить в таблице `projects` выбранные виды оплат.

Я делал следующее:

**фрагмент формы из projects/new.html.erb:**

```
<%= @payment_types.each do |type| %> 
<%= check_box_tag 'project[payment_type_ids][]', type.id %> 
<%= type.name %> 

<% end %>
```

**controllers/projects_controller.rb**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

def index

end

def new
  @project = Project.new
  @project.documents.build
  @payment_types = PaymentType.all
end

def create
  @payment_types = PaymentType.all
  @project = Project.create(project_params)

  if @project.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Your project successfully created.'
    redirect_to @project
  else
    render :new
  end  
end

private

def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:title, :description, :price, :skill, :location, 
    :payment_type_ids, :anonymity, :price_category, :category_id, documents_attributes: [:attachment_uid])
end
```

При создании объекта вываливается ошибка:

> Unpermitted parameters: payment_type_ids, attachment

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что необходимо добавить в `permitted parameters` и как правильно сохранить выбранные значения из чекбоксов в моем случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StrongParams работает с массивами несколько [хитрее](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).

> To declare that the value in params must be an array of permitted scalar values, map the key to an empty array:
>
> params.permit(id: [])

В твоём случае это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
params.require(:project).permit(:title, :description, :price, :skill, :location, :anonymity, :price_category, :category_id, ocuments_attributes: [:attachment_uid], payment_type_ids: [])
```

Comment: теперь руается на строку: @project = Project.create(project_params). Could not find table 'payment_types_projects'

Comment: Нет промежуточной таблички. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: @StefanHansch это уже совсем другой вопрос. Параметры же успешно прошли :) Значит, контроллер отработал правильно, дыра уже в модели.